# TypeError: undefined is not an object ('_this.props')

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I can't solve this problem. Can you help me.
evaluating 'this.props.speciesSelection.modalize'

```
<BarcodeInput
        speciesSelection={this.props.speciesSelection}
        species={species[0]}
        barcode={{ manufacturerValue: "", codeValue: "" }}
        onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
      />


 class BarcodeInput extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  onPrefixPress = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    this.props.speciesSelection.modalize.open();
    this.props.speciesSelection.modalizeOpened = true;
 }
```

Red Box when I touch to button onPrefixPress

Comment: interface OwnProps extends ComponentProps {
      speciesSelection: any;
    }

Comment: Can you post full code?

Comment: Can you show the part where you are calling `onPrefixPress`?

Comment: `<Button
          onPress={() => this.onPrefixPress()}
          transparent
          style={styles.btn}
        >`

Comment: @SanyamJain code so big

Comment: Post BarcodeInput component and where you are impl that component.

Comment: Please post the part where you render <BarcodeInput />

Comment: Use https://www.hastebin.com / http://del.dog / https://gist.github.com

Comment: @SanyamJain [https://gist.github.com/bekanur98/7f8fe4a6f6b3e13bebf91a30bf865068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to invoke a function (passed via props) which is undefined.
Make `speciesSelection` prop optional.

```
interface Props {
  species: Species;
  barcode: BarcodeState;
  speciesSelection?: any;
  onChangeText: (prop: keyof BarcodeState, value: string) => void;
}

interface State { }

class BarcodeInput extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  onPrefixPress = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    this.props.speciesSelection && this.props.speciesSelection.modalize.open();
    this.props.speciesSelection && this.props.speciesSelection.modalizeOpened = true;
  }
```

or check why it's undefined.